# Which Certificate Store does Jenkins service use in Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, jenkins, visual-studio

Some of my VS projects require manifest signing certificates to build.

If I install them in my user account's `Personal` directory, then `msbuild` completes successfully from the command line.

If I then reconfigure the Jenkins service to log in as my user, then the build completes successfully from Jenkins.

However, if I switch Jenkins to the default Jenkins service user and install these certificates in `Jenkins\Personal`, they are not detected.

Where should certificates be installed to allow Jenkins to access them?

Comment: If it's a normal Windows Service, try the LocalMachine Store

Comment: Hi Peter, I had tried the LocalMachine store too and found it did not work - apologies for not mentioning it in the question.  I will go back and confirm that at some point, but for now it's acceptable for me to run Jenkins as a user.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the certificates in the "machine" (not "user") store, they will be available to all users running on this machine, including the Jenkins service account.

If the certificates are actual files that needs to be accessed, and Jenkins service runs under a pre-defined service account (eg. LocalService or NetworkService), the user profile folders for those users reside under `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles`.